# Neo4j thousands of properties on one node, limitations

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I understand that this approach is really very far from the best practices of the schema modeling in Neo4j, but is it possible to have thousands of properties on one single node. For my filtering and aggregation logic, I was able to gain the best performance via denormalizing the data into the node properties.

I use OGM and dynamic properties:

```
@Properties(prefix = "properties", allowCast = true)
private Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
```

But I afraid that with this approach, the number of properties in one single node, may eventually growth to thousands. Is there any limitations in Neo4j for the number of properties in one single node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such limit on the number of properties on a node as you read on this  neo4j question:

```
 https://community.neo4j.com/t5/neo4j-graph-platform/best-practices-on-number-of-properties-for-a-node/m-p/22891
```

However, when you create a lot of properties, the query execution time will suffer. It also suggests to change the data model and do a refactoring to create additional nodes/relationships when it happens.